# Create Azure Databricks Token using ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-databricks

I need to create a token in Azure Databricks using ARM template.
I am able to create Azure Databricks using ARM template but unable to create token in Azure Databricks using ARM template

Following is the template which i have used to create Azure Databricks

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01- 
01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"workspaceName": {
"type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The name of the Azure Databricks workspace to create."
  }
},
"pricingTier": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "premium",
  "allowedValues": [
    "standard",
    "premium"
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "description": "The pricing tier of workspace."
  }
},
"location": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Location for all resources."
  }
}
},
"variables": {
"managedResourceGroupName": "[concat('databricks-rg-', 
parameters('workspaceName'), '-', uniqueString(parameters('workspaceName'), 
resourceGroup().id))]"
},
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
  "name": "[parameters('workspaceName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
  "sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('pricingTier')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "ManagedResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedResourceGroupName'))]"
  }
}
],
"outputs": {
"workspace": {
  "type": "object",
  "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces', parameters('workspaceName')))]"
}
}
}
```

Kindly let me know how to create tokens in Azure Databricks using ARM template

Answer (score 5):

I see in a comment that you ask if it is possible to create a token using a script. It is now possible!

Databricks has a token API: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/tokens.html

Check out this blog: https://cloudarchitected.com/2020/01/using-azure-ad-with-the-azure-databricks-api/

It shows how easy it is to create a databricks token using AAD, and a few other methods.

I have some Python Code that I use automate this task. I would extend it to automatically add the token to a key vault of some sort. Here is a sample:

```
import requests
import adal
import json

# set variables 
clientId = "<Service Principal Id>"
tenantId = "<Tenant Id>"
clientSecret = "<Service Principal Secret>"
subscription_id = "<Subscription Id>"
resource_group = "<Resource Group Name>"
databricks_workspace = "<Databricks Workspace Name>"
dbricks_location = "<Databricks Azure Region i.e. westus>"



# Acquire a token to authenticate against Azure management API
authority_url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+tenantId
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource='https://management.core.windows.net/',
    client_id=clientId,
    client_secret=clientSecret
)
azToken = token.get('accessToken')



# Acquire a token to authenticate against the Azure Databricks Resource
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    resource="2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d",
    client_id=clientId,
    client_secret=clientSecret
)
adbToken = token.get('accessToken')


# Format Request API Url
dbricks_api = "https://{}.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0".format(dbricks_location)


# Request Authentication
dbricks_auth = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(adbToken),
    "X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token": azToken,
    "X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id": ("/subscriptions/{}/resourceGroups/{}/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/{}".format(subscription_id, resource_group, databricks_workspace) )
    }


# Optional Paramters 
payload = {
    "comment": "This token is generated through AAD and Databricks APIs", # optional parameter
    # "lifetime_seconds": 3600 # optional parameter. If not passed then it is indefinte
}


# Request and Send Data to Create a Databricks Token
data = requests.post("{}/token/create".format(dbricks_api), headers= dbricks_auth, json=payload)

# display the response data
data.status_code
data.content

# Decode response, get token, and print token
dict_content = json.loads(data.content.decode('utf-8'))
token = dict_content.get('token_value')
print("This is the databricks token: {}".format(token))
```

Comment: You're the best! That perfectly worked for me. It still would be nice to be able to perfrom this directly in an ARM template, but your Code definetly made my day! Hence, imho this should be an accepted answer.

Comment: Now it’s easy via terraform provider for Databricks

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible today. It is a requested feature here on uservoice https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks/suggestions/35257819-expose-api-key-during-arm-deployment

(Please upvote)

Currently you have to log into the web UI manually and generate a token. Even the REST API doesn't support this.

Comment: Can we generate token using Powershell script ? If that is possible , Kindly provide me some reference

Comment: I'm afraid not. It can only be done manually today. I would expect it to be added to the arm template in the future as I've seen others requesting it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use [**azure.databricks.cicd.tools**](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools) in your CD pipeline to [**create a new bearer token**](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/blob/master/Public/New-DatabricksBearerToken.ps1).

You need to use [**Connect-Databricks**](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/azure.databricks.cicd.tools/wiki/Connect-Databricks) to connect to your workspace first. I usually use the AADwithOrgId method to authenticate to the Databricks workspace:

```
Connect-Databricks -Region <String> -ApplicationId <String> -Secret <String> -DatabricksOrgId <String> -TenantId <String>
```

The service principal should have the Contributor role on your resource group and be added a an admin in your Databricks workspace.